# SQL Server - insert multiple values - what is the right way?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a .NET application that works against a SQL Server. This app gets data from a remote third party API, and I need to insert that data to my database in a transaction.

First I delete all existing data from the tables, then I insert each row of data that I get from the API.

I wrote a stored procedure that accepts parameters and does the insert. then I call that stored procedure in a loop with a transaction from .NET.

I'm guessing there's a smarter way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can insert multiple data like this: `insert into table (col1,col2) values (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)` and why do you delete the old data?

Comment: Calling a stored procedure in a loop is a great way to do it. Why do you have doubts? Is it too slow?

Comment: @juergend I need to delete the old data because the data stored in my db is a copy of the data I'm getting from the API. the new data replaces the old one - so I do a delete before.

Comment: @Gabe it's not that it's slow (although I haven't tested it on production - only on my dev machine) but when I call the SP it seems to me like I'm moving information across the wire with several calls instead of one bulk. wasn't sure this was the right thing to do...

Comment: Each call of the sproc is a separate transfer "across the wire", but the data has to be moved regardless. What I would consider is having a single batch with many `EXEC` statements.

Comment: @Gabe so leave it as a stored procedure and in my loop build a string with many "EXE MY_STORED_PROCEDURE;" commands one after the other?

Comment: If your goal is to reduce network traffic, only select the info you do not already have ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do. Use profiling to determine how big your batches should be: 10? 100? 1000?

Comment: Truncate does not write to the Transaction Log like delete, but for tables used in replication you must use delete.

Comment: Which is the data format exposed by remote third party API?

Comment: @Dd2 - internal object structure that's given to me as a row collection by the DLL I was given.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing thousands or maybe even tens of thousands you can probably do best with table valued [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you're doing more than that then you should probably look at doing the dedicated SQL server bulk insert [feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That might not work great transactionally if I remember correctly.

Either way truncate is way faster than delete.

What I've done in the past to avoid needing transactions is create two tables, and use another for deciding which is the active one. That way you always have a table with valid data and no write locks.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you maybe have links to resources that I can read about what you've mentioned?

Comment: I added URLs. Sorry the Markdown's not correct, my phone doesn't have the fancy editor. I'll try to fix it later.